# Java 8 break forEach with alternative action

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I do have the following class:

```
public class CloseableRepeater<R extends Closeable> {

    /**
     * Repeats the supplier until the stop condition becomes <code>true</code>.
     *
     * @param supplier The supplier to be repeated.
     * @param until  The stop condition.
     * @param times  The maximum repeat times.
     * @return The result.
     */
    public Optional<R> repeat(Supplier<R> supplier, Predicate<R> until, int times) {
        R r = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            r = supplier.get();
            if (until.test(r)) {
                break;
            } else {
                try {
                    r.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }
        }
        return Optional.of(r);
    }

}
```

Basically, it repeats an action until a condition is fulfilled and closes the items that do not fulfill it.

---

**My question**

Is there any possibility to rewrite the method `repeat` using functional programming?

---

I know the code is good enough as it is, but the goal of this question is to improve my functional programming skills and to find its limitations

The closest I've got is:

```
public Optional<R> repeat(Supplier<R> supplier, Predicate<R> until, int times) {
    return IntStream.range(0, times).mapToObj(i -> supplier.get()).filter(until).findFirst();
}
```

but the `close` part is missing.

Comment: You don't need to rewrite this. What you have is good enough. So just keep it. Apart from that, you may need `Optional.ofNullable` since `r` can presumably be `null`. Also you can keep `r = supplier.get();` outside of the loop and reuse the same instance IMO.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I'm happy with `Optional.of` because it throws `NullPointerException` if value is null. I know the code is good enough, but the goal of this question is to improve my functional programming skills and to find its limitations.

Comment: @EugenCovaci it can definitely be improved. I'm writing an answer but you can drop the imperative loop and just use stream operations.

Comment: @VLAZ Dropping only  the imperative loop would be a minor improvement.

Comment: @EugenCovaci as I said "and just use stream operations". Although I'm having to do a bit of research in exactly how. I expected some sort of common stream operations to be available but apparently they aren't (maybe in Java 8?), so I'm doing light research in how to exactly do this in Java. I don't code as much in Java as I used to, so I'm slightly behind here.

Comment: Theoretically your `close` would have to come before or during `filter`. No matter what, filter will leave you with one or the other: a stream of "true against predicate" elements (for returning), or a stream of "false against predicate" (for closing), not both.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Right, it's the fundamental issue here.

Comment: Maybe `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` in Java 9 might help?

Comment: OK, I'm actually a bit stumped now. The general idea I had was to start off with `Stream.generate(supplier).limit(times)` which replaces the `for` loop. However, afterwards you have to consume items one by one by some criterial. Apparently Java 9 has `takeWhile` but that's going to basically do the same as `filter` in that it only leaves you with items that match the predicate. Instead we need something like `executeWhile` that takes an item, performs an operation and returns whether to continue with the next. And then we can just grab the next item in the stream. But you can't do that, either

Comment: because once a stream is operated on, you can't just get *the next item*, apparently. Once you narrow down the items in the stream, you're done. You could do a `reduce` where you test each item and return it or close it but  that will traverse the whole stream, even if you just want to return the first item that matches the predicate. Using a partitioning collector is fancier where you can collect all items that *don't* match a predicate separately and then just close them at once but it ends up with the same fundamental limitation as `reduce` in that it materializes and traverses everything

Comment: from the stream. So, you can't really to do this cleanly. You can do it "dirty" and add an intermediate operation that mutates the stream (e.g., `filter( /* close item or return true() */).findFirst()`) but I'm not a fan of it. So, the cleanest thing I can see is `Stream.generate(supplier).limit(times).iterator()` and then manually consume items from the iterator...but it's barely an improvement. The best I can figure using streams only is to make a stream from the supplier, collect using a partitioning collector and set the downstream collector

Comment: to either close (for `false`) or merge leaving the first item (for `true`). However, I'm not really sure how this would be implemented - my Collectors knowledge is bad.

Comment: Why are you returning an `Optional` when it is never empty, but rather your code will produce a `NullPointerException` when no `R` has been found?

Comment: @VLAZ you mean something like `dropWhile(until.negate())`?

Comment: @Holger yes, except you cannot then close the items you've dropped. Java prefers you not to modify stuff in flight, so I'm trying to keep to those constraints, although you *could* of course have a `dropWhile` with an operation that mutates each item. EDIT: now I thought about something - you can have a `dropWhile` that adds items to a separate collection and you *then* close all of them? Still a bit ugly but ever so slightly more "Java stream"-like.

Comment: @VLAZ I’m not advertising a stream solution, the loop looks preferable to me. But I was referring to your comment about `takeWhile`, which isn’t fitting the goal about getting the first element. But I think we agree that there is no adequate stream solution.

Comment: @Holger The only case my code produces a NullPointerException is when `times` is zero or negative. I'm fine with this behaviour, otherwise I would have used  `Optional.ofNullable`

Comment: Indeed, I now see that if there was at least one nonmatching `R`, it does not throw, but returning a non-matching, already closed object when no match has been found is not better…

Comment: @Holger yes, we absolutely agree. I was folding `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` into one since it's fundamentally the same unsuitable result. I was thinking of streams as broadly a uniform iterator (sort of) where you can move *forward* consuming items but Java doesn't. Moreover, there is the underlying assumption that streams might executed in parallel. So, at least from Java perspective, there doesn't seem to be a clean solution. You either (potentially) consume all items or not, we don't want to materialise more than what we need and we don't want interfering, we're stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Following @VinceEmigh's comment, I think I have found the solution:

```
   public Optional<R> functionalRepeat(Supplier<R> supplier, Predicate<R> until, int times) {
        return Stream.generate(supplier).limit(times).filter(until.or(t -> {
            try {
                t.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Ignore
            }
            return false;
        })).findFirst();
    }
```

The idea is to call the `close` while filtering by chaining the `until` predicate with another one that does the closing, using the fact that it is a short-circuiting logical OR involved.

The filtering condition is true iff the `until` predicate is true, so they are logically equivalent.

**Update**

Actually, the above code is **not** equivalent to the original one, since it produces an empty optional when no match, while the original code produces an optional containing the last non-matching element.

Comment: You should avoid Stream code relying on the processing order. E.g., this code will not work in parallel.

Comment: @Holger Why do you think I rely on  the processing order? Please explain.

Comment: When you have the elements `A B C D E F` and the predicate would accept `C` and `D`, `findFirst()` is guaranteed to return `C`, but your code assumes that this implies that it could never process `D`. This is not guaranteed and, in practice, your predicate may have to process `D` in a parallel stream. The stream will correctly drop `D` when there’s also the accepted `C`, earlier in *encounter order*, but you haven’t closed `D` then.

Comment: @Holger I've got your point. Anyway, this is working fine for sequential streams.

Comment: I suggest changing `IntStream.range(0, times).mapToObj(i -> supplier.get())` to `Stream.generate(supplier).limit(times)`. There is no reason to use a limited int stream other than mimic *exactly* how a `for` loop works. Since you never even need the `i`, you are only interested in the items, you're better off making a stream of *those* directly.

Answer (score 1):

A loop is not bad and better suited to this specific problem. But you can clean it up a bit:

```
public Optional<R> repeat(Supplier<R> supplier, Predicate<R> until, int times) {
    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        R r = supplier.get();
        if(until.test(r)) return Optional.of(r);
        try {
            r.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

The intention of the method surely was to return an empty optional when no match has been found (while a `null` closable should not be supported and lead to a `NullPointerException`). It’s better when this is handled by the code flow intrinsically instead of pre-initializing a variable with `null`, which led to the situation that your original code couldn’t tell apart a `null` result and no existing element and even worse, could return a wrong element.

It’s worth considering using `<R extends AutoCloseable>` to raise the flexibility, you only have to change the `catch(IOException e)` to `catch(Exception e)` while existing callers continue to work, but more use cases are possible.